# Insert FileName with Absolute Path

Tags: batch-file

I have a Script that search for files with wildcards and inserts the name of FileNames (alone) in another File. I want to Insert Filename with Full path. Both Files are in Same Location

For Example:

```
dir /b X/Y/Z/FileName*.txt /ON > X/Y/Z/AnotherFileName.txt
```

Comment: It is quite odd to see `dir` used with POSIX `[shell]` and options in POSIX shell are prefixed with `-` or `--`, not `/`. Are you sure you are not talking about DOS batch?

Comment: Thanks David. im not sure about script type, Script is executing Fine at Informatica PC/IICS. But it has only filename , i needed it with path.

Comment: In windows, `/` introduces switches and **backslash** is used to separate directory names in a path. Note also that `AnotherFileName.txt` will be listed in your output

Comment: You could use `where` instead of `dir`. Example: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "X\Y\Z":"FileName*.txt"  1>"X\Y\Z\AnotherFileName.txt"```

Answer (score 1):

If your main focus is on getting the *full path* of the files and storing them in the file (AnotherFileName.txt) inside the *same directory* of the matched filenames.

Then you can use this batch script :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in ('%*') do (
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%b in (`dir /s /b ^"%%a^"`) do (
    echo "%%fb" > "%%~dpbAnotherFileName.txt"
    echo Pasted "%%~fb" in "%%~dpbAnotherFileName.txt"
  )
 )
```

For this batch script to function, you need to pass it the wildcard string that you would normally perform with `dir` command.

Suppose if you saved this script as *getmelist.bat*, then you need to enter it's name in command prompt and pass the filename argument like :-

`getmelist.bat X/Y/Z/FileName*.txt`

and it will save the results inside the *"X\Y\Z\AnotherFileName.txt"*

**Note:-** If you did some recursive search, and there seem to be files that match on different directories, like:-
`getmelist.bat X\Y\Z*filename*.txt`
Then this will create *AnotherFileName.txt* file with the string of Absolute path in each of the files directory. That's I have added the `Echo` command to let user know.

**Tip:-** *Run `for /?` and `dir /?` in command prompt to know how the script functions. And if you find something difficult to understand in the help, feel free to comment your questions/confusions. *

> In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
>
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
>
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
>
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
>
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
>
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
>
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
>
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
>
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
>
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
>
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file